# LINQ - Select min count

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings which contain `X` in them. I want to select list(s) with the *minimum count of `X`* in them. For example:

`CountMin("AXBXX", "AAX")` will return `AAX`.

How can I write this qith LINQ in a concise way ?

Comment: Did you want a list of the strings with the minimum count or just one of them? The accepted answer is just one, but your question reads like you'd like all of the strings with the minimum count of `X`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static string CountMin(IList<string> inputList) 
{ 
    if (inputList == null || !inputList.Any()) return null;
    var result = inputList.Select(s => new 
                          { 
                             Item = s,
                             Count => s.Count(ch => ch == 'X')
                          })
                          .OrderBy(item => item.Count).First().Item;
}
```

Snippet assumes that all elements on list are different to `null`. If you need it, it could be easily improved.

You can also omit temporary class:

```
inputList.OrderBy(s => s.Count(c => c == 'X')).First();
```

Comment: Nice. Better than mine as it is better to count 'X' rather than Replace them (and repeatedly determining Length is not great either).

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] list = {"AXBXX", "AAX", "AXX"};

string result = (from word in list
              select new { word, wordLen = (word.Length - (word.Replace("X", "")).Length) })
                .OrderBy(x => x.wordLen).First().word;

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that will get you all of the minimum `X` strings from the list.

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string>()
{
    "AXB",
    "ABXXC",
    "ABX",
};

var minimumXs =
    listOfStrings
        .GroupBy(x => x.Count(y => y == 'X'))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
        .Take(1)
        .SelectMany(x => x);
```

That gives me:

```
AXB 
ABX
```